# Using JavaScript variables in CSS (Vue App)

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, vuejs3

## Dynamically Styled Component

I'm trying to create dynamically styled component, by **setting CSS values from JavaScript variables without using Document Web API's,** I mean methods like `Document.getElementById()`
&
`Document.querySelector()`.

I'm using **Vue.JS** btw,
And I came up with a code that looks like this:

```
<template>
  <div class="badge-container" :style="myStyle">
    <slot></slot>
  </div>
<template>
```

```
<script>
  setup(props) {
    const myStyle = ref(`--color: ${props.color}`)
    return{myStyle}
    }
</script>
```

```
<style>
.badge-container::after {
  background-color: var(--color);
  }
</style>
```

**It works fine**, but only for **one variable**, & I want to use **multiple** variables, how do I pass multiple variables to CSS from JS.

I've tried to convert **myStyle** to an object to pass multiple values but I've failed.
I could put all the style like this `<div :style="color: ${color}">`

but the problem in this way that the div style will changed and I want to change **::after** `.badge-container::after`

Is there anyway to make this happen, **without using Document Web API's Or JSX**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this feature of Vue3: [v-bind-in-css](https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-css-features.html#v-bind-in-css)

So that you can get a fully dynamic styling based on actual state

```html
<script setup>
const theme = {
  color: 'red'
}
</script>

<template>
  <p>hello</p>
</template>

<style scoped>
p {
  color: v-bind('theme.color');
}
</style>
```

As shown here in [this playground](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#eNp9j81qw0AMhF9l2YtbiL131zX0PfaS2GrtsD9Ckl1K8LtX67SQNpCbZiR9w1zsG2KzLmBb2/FAM4phkAV7n4acWIxMEMG8motPxgw5ZGpNRTBWPm0+de76pOcqBCKGo4AqYzrsJwghd67AOnezVMnyFcDwkBFGdfAPf61Pcxqfqj272c3q+eU3sHz29mDniJmkjkdszpyTNtgZ/mfB3rZXavG0YtHeTiLIrXP8PpTeZ24yfTidGlqSzJoHHOsT5U8GUrC3hxuGU3MFqgnSCAT0iPnv9I5bsNpos9s3E/OIig==).